# Potential bug in profile views

Tags: bug, profile-page

How is it possible that you were lastly active years before you were a member?
I took some random example:

[image]

How is the time you are a member calculated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is it possible that you were lastly active years before you were a member

It is *13th of October*. NOT OCT 2013.

> How is the time you are a member calculated?

It is calculated by taking the date when you create an account in Stack Overflow.

## Not a bug

Comment: The bug is that they use the confusing us style for the dates.

Comment: @user000001 well you can still view the timestamp by hovering over it.